# How to update to mingw-gcc 4.8.2?

Tags: c++, mingw, gcc4.8

I want to use Regular expression in c++11 and gcc 4.8.2 supports it. But the MinGW installer only supports up to gcc 4.8.1. How can I update it to gcc 4.8.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manually install it yourself. There's a MinGW-w64 distribution for [**4.8.2 available here**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.8.2/).

You'll need [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to extract the file contents. After you unzip it to a location of you're choosing just add the `bin` subdirectory from there to your environment `path` and you should be good to go.

For example, if you extracted the toolchain into `x:\mingw32-4.8.2` then add `x:\mingw32-4.8.2\bin` using

> setx path "%path%;*x*:\mingw32-4.8.2\bin"

Restart the Command Prompt for it to take effect. If you have an older mingw version installed you might want to remove that to avoid potential conflicts.

Comment: If you found my response helpful, don't forget you can upvote and accept it.