# MinGW alternative for eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, mingw

I'm trying to get started into threading on C++ in eclipse. I want to create Windows applications, and I found that MinGW can't work with threads. I read that others like Cygwin aren't totally compatible.

How do I write threaded programs that works on multiple platforms?

Comment: _"I found that MinGW can't work with threads"_ That's not true.

Comment: Welcome to this site. Unfortunately your question appears off-topic here. For details about asking (on-topic) questions you might want to have look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Check [Does gcc 4.7.1 support threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210102/does-gcc-4-7-1-support-threads) 1st please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) fully supports threads, GCC 4.8 fully implements them.

So if you must use threads, use C++'s ones. Avoid messing with pthreads, they are **very** error-prone.

Also, possibly related question: [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922382/how-to-update-to-mingw-gcc-4-8-2)

Answer (score 1):

MinGW support pthreads. But, if you want that your code support many platforms, maybe you must see [Boost Threads](http://www.boost.org/).

[Boost Threads 1.56.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/thread.html)